# Somases e Tabela dinâmica pelo R

Tags: r

Estou precisando fazer um cálculo no RStudio que a princípio é simples de fazer no excel.
Temos uma tabela com duas colunas, uma com códigos de ocupação (Coluna Ocupação), e outra coluna com dois códigos para mulheres, sendo 0 para homens e 1 para mulheres (Coluna Mulher).
Preciso somar o número de mulheres por ocupação, e com este valor calcular o percentual de mulheres que cada ocupação.
Nossa tabela original apresenta mais de 360 códigos de ocupação, com mais de 250 mil observações, impossibilitando a utilização do excel.

Dados:

```
df_1 <- structure(list(Ocup = c(11, 12, 13, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
13, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 11, 12, 11, 13, 13, 11, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 13, 
11, 12, 11), Mulher = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: Olá, @Mário. Evite postar imagens como tabela de dados. Não é possível reproduzir seu exemplo desta forma.

Comment: Execute isso em `R`: `dput(head(dados, 30))`. Após, copie e cole aqui.

Comment: Olá @neves, mas são muitos dados aproximadamente 212 mil observações.

Comment: São apenas duas colunas, certo? Execute a função que te disse (ela retornará apenas 30 linhas). Depois, copie e cole aqui. Ou mantenha minha edição.

Comment: structure(list(Ocup = c(11, 12, 13, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 
11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 11, 12, 11, 13, 13, 11, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 
13, 11, 12, 11), Mulher = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @neves, vale a pena observar que temos neste caso apenas 3 tipos de Ocupação, sendo as de código 11,12 e 13 e a coluna mulheres onde o número 1 indica ser mulher e 0 para homens. Na tabela original temos mais de 433 ocupações e precisamos calcular o percentual de mulheres de cada ocupação.

Comment: Considere o nome do banco de dados como `df_1`. Veja se isso resolve: `df_1 %>% 
  filter(Mulher == 1) %>% 
  group_by(Ocup) %>% 
  summarise(contagem_por_grupo = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percentagem = contagem_por_grupo / sum(contagem_por_grupo) * 100)`

Comment: Tudo certo @neves, muito obrigado pela ajuda.